# Update Maven Repo

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

Can you update http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/ST4
?

The latest version there is 4.0.4 and you all are on 4.0.6.

FYI: the ONLY reason I am asking this here in SO is due to this page: http://www.stringtemplate.org/support.html

which states this is the preferred question/answer mechanism.

Comment: Please check official maven repo browser: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.antlr%22%20AND%20a%3A%22ST4%22

Comment: Clicking the link you supplied shows only 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 (as well as two release candidates which I am not interested in).  Nothing for 4.0.6.  I think you should take back the -1...

Comment: I would definitely take back the -1, however /"It wasn't me" (c) Shaggy/ who gave you that..